# possibility to toggle between http and https?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

how is it possible to toggle between http and https? I want to handle it from .htaccess

### .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}            !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(secure)\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              https://%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

### httpd.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ini/ssl/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

when requesting....

- http://secure.domain.com the page is blank
- https://secure.domain.com the page is accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `Redirect permanent / https://secure.domain.com/` to your *.80 Virtual Host?

Or if you only want http://secure.domain.com to redirect, then add another Virtual Host for that ServerAlias only.

Comment: Best and easiest solution.

Comment: So give it an upvote then. :)